# Installing Protractor for Angular JS in VScode

Tags: angularjs, protractor, npm-install, gulp-protractor

I have npm installed globally and installed protractor globally as well. When I check for the node version it returns proper version, but when I am trying to check the version of protractor after installing it gives me the below error. can anyone help me with whats going wrong here?

*protractor : The term 'protractor' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ protractor --version*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to config the global protractor into `PATH` environment variable through
below two steps:

1. get npm global package install path by execute following cmd which will print out an absolute folder path.

```
npm config get prefix
```

2. add the `install path/bin` into `PATH` environment variable 
   For example the step 1 print out `xxx\yyy`, you should add `xxx\yyy\bin;` into `PATH` on Windows, Or add `xxx\yyy\bin:` on Linux.

**Important**:  try `protrator --version` in new cmd window, Don't try again in previous opened cmd window.